# how to convert variable type integer to double

Tags: type-conversion

I want to convert integers to double in the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a , b;
    double c;
    cout<<"Enter two integers: ";
    cin>>a>>b;
    try
    {
        if (b == 0)
            throw 0;
    }
    catch (int a)
    {
        cout<<"You made a division by zero?"<<endl<<a;
    }
    c = static_cast<double>(a/b);
    cout<<"The division  is: "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<c;

}
```

How to change the code to output the double value?

Comment: I think you should cast both a nd b

Comment: You should cast *at least* one argument - either `a` or `b` (or both)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you should cast not a result of division but variables itself, to get double value. All three options works.

```
int a, b;
    double c;
    std::cout << "Enter two integers: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    try
    {
        if (b == 0)
            throw 0;
    }
    catch (int a)
    {
        std::cout << "You made a division by zero?" << std::endl << a;
    }
    c = static_cast<double>(a) / b;
    c = a / static_cast<double>(b);
    c = static_cast<double>(a) / static_cast<double>(b);

    std::cout << "The division  is: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << c;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the result of the division, you should cast the operands instead.

Don't use an exception to catch a condition that you already catch using a simple `if`. Just use the `if`, and use an `else` to skip the division if the second operand is zero.

```
int a , b;
double c;
cout<<"Enter two integers: ";
cin>>a>>b;
if (b == 0) {
  cout<<"You made a division by zero?"<<endl;
} else {
  c = static_cast<double>(a) / static_cast<double>(b);
  cout<<"The division  is: "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<c;
}
```